# Python video display using GPIO of raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project to display a video using Raspberry Pi, and I need help with coding please, here are some functions that I want:

1. When GPIO pin (High) play a video, it will check the GPIO pin status every 13 seconds as long at it is high it will keep displaying video. if it is (low) the video pause.
2. If the video is finished it will start the second video.
3. The program will run for 15 minutes max then start over again.

Right now, I'm on step 1. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually on this site, we like to see a some type of a first attempt. Have you done any research at all on how to accomplish this? Perhaps a good first step: Just display a video in python. Good? Next step: Just check to see if a GPIO pin is currently High. Good? Next step: Implement some type of timer, to check this continually, and display some text. Next step: Integrate everything together.

Comment: Thank you, the project involves converting Analogue to Digital,   I did use MCP3008 and I was able to play a video using the code below, I want to display the video  only if some data is detected  and it pauses when no data is detected, don't know how to make the code for this condition ?

Comment: thank you i did ,now i want to display the video only if there is detected data from Def analogue(channel1) fuction ,any help pls ?
#Function to read SPI data from MCP3008 chip
def analogInput (Channel):
    adc=spi.xfer2[1,(8+channel)<<4,0]
    data=((adc[1]&3)<<8)+adc[2]
    return data
while True:
    Videodisplay= analogInput(channel)
            omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', '-b', movie1])
            player = True
            sleep(3)
      else:
            os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
            omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', '-b', movie2])
            player = False

Comment: You should edit your question with your progress. ^ Is unreadable